# Group by pairs of values of the same column in SQL with timeseries

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have the following problem,
I have a table like this one:

```
[login] [time]  [action]
bou     3:15:21 display
bou     3:16:45 connect
bou     3:17:12 disconnect
bou     3:17:15 connect
bou     3:19:12 disconnect
bou     3:21:15 connect
```

What I want to do is simply get the number of times each consecutive pairs of actions that are done in the same hour appear. So the result should be something like

```
[login] [time] [action_1] [action_2] [count]
bou     3      display    connect    1
bou     3      disconnect connect    2
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lead()` and some date arithmetic:

```
select login, date_trunc('hour', time), action, next_action, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lead(action) over (partition by login, date_trunc('hour', time)
                                order by time
                               ) as next_action
      from t
     ) t
group by login, date_trunc('hour', time), action, next_action;
```

This gets all pairs.  If you only want pairs that start with something other than `connect` then add `where action <> 'connecdt'` to the outer query.

Comment: Great answer. Wouldn't that show the "connect -> disconnect" pairs as well though? I'm not used to the lead function's behavior, so just asking for knowledge :)

Comment: @AnthonyDrogon . . . Good point.  The sample data suggests that there is some sort of filtering going on, although the question asks for pairs in general.